# Sails.js self-referencing hierarchical model - exhaustive query?

Tags: mysql, sails.js, waterline

I have a model which include regions, which can be nested (region within a region), products that are available in certain regions and groups which also are reside within a region: [image: model]

The purpose of this is that I can restrict the availability of product to certain groups based on the group's region. The nested region hierarchy is so that I have more flexibility in the association (I can have "multiple dimensions", e.g. geographical / demography).

I am developing with sails.js/waterline and while to create the model is relatively straight forward, I am not sure how I can easily/efficiently query the model.

My main use case would be to get all the products available for a group (so this should find all the regions the group is in, either directly, or by hierarchy (e.g. group1 --> region2.1 --> region2) and find all the products available for that group (in the above example, all products in region 2.1 and 2).

Is there a way to execute such a query directly? The only alternative I thought of was to make an additional tables which associates product to group directly and update it whenever a new product is available or when there are changes in association but that seems to be error prone.